# Stimulus Framework - connect() not work when change with javascript

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I create a stimulus controller and use on a div element.
Now when change innerHTML of this div element with click on a button, text change but color not change to red and connect() not work.

```
<div data-controller="test">
    <span>This text color change to red</span>
    <button type="button" data-action="test#changeColor">click</button>
</div>
```

test_controller.js

```
...
connect() {
    this.element.style.color = "red";
}
changeColor(event) {
    this.element.innerHTML = "<span>HelloWorld!</span>"
}
...
```

Comment: you need to add a data-target to you span, then change the targets style on the click action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues

1. You need to target the span, as `this.element` will be the element with the `data-controller` on it. See https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets
2. You will need to set the target's color in the `connect` method AND the controller's changeColor method for it to change when the element connects (DOM loads) and when the button is clicked. See https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/lifecycle-callbacks

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['label'];

  connect() {
    this.changeColor();
  }

  changeColor() {
    const element = this.labelTarget;

    element.innerText = 'HelloWorld!';
    element.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<div data-controller="test">
  <span data-test-target="label">This text color change to red</span>
  <button type="button" data-action="test#changeColor">click</button>
</div>
```